# How to fix nodemon app crash after added mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express, mongoose

I am setting up an environment with mongodb, node.js, express.js and mongoose. mongoDB is in its own container, and the same with the rest.

It all worked fine until I tried to add mongoose.

After this line was added

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
```

I got an error-message when a ran docker-compose up

[Error-message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExRq8.png)

This is my package.json

[Package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wusWa.png)

This is my dockerfile for the api
[Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAGoi.png)

Does anyone knwo how to fix this?

Comment: Clearly says that you don't have mongoose installed, have you installed it?

Comment: Yes, as you see in package.json I have